# Sequence Diagrams and Java

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram

I'm reading about Sequence Diagrams and I've found an exercise (multiple choice) which envolves Java code and it got me kind of confused... Can you help me to choose the right option, in order to get it clearer for me? I think it'd be simple for you. Many thanks in advance.

Here's the direct link to the image (hosted in ImageShack):
[Sequence Diagrams and Java](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/1482/seqdiagram.jpg)

What answer would you choose?

Comment: If you explain your thought process and guess it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Well, for Class A you have to be focused on function s() and function t(). For function s() you have the following: function s() { dosomething; d.r(); } . But I'm in doubt with function t().

Answer (score 0):

The diagram shows a process calling a.s() which calls c.w(), which calls d.u(), which calls a.t().

So functions() on a must include c.w().

Can you apply that logic to the rest of the arrows?

Comment: But how does this help me to figure it out?

Comment: So the bottom two arrows show that c must have a function called x() which contains a call to a.r()...

Answer (score 0):

One hint: the class diagram provided on the right is not really relevant to finding the answer.

Another hint: the call from d to a.t() is different from the other calls in that it just returns instead of calling another method.

A remark: in Java, all method calls ultimately return or throw an exception unless the system exits prematurely. This makes this sequence diagram a bit odd - only one of the method calls (the one I mention above) is shown to return. The rest of the diagram shows a chaining of method calls to-and-fro between classes. This is not a common way classes collaborate in Java and seems to be constructed purely to as an excercise to test your understanding of UML.

Comment: If the unlabelled arrow from a.t() back to d is a return message instead of a call, shouldn't the arrow be dashed and the activation block for d.u() extend all the way down to the call to c.x()?

Comment: There are so many dialects of UML around that I never really keep track of the formal notation, so you might absolutely be right. However, looking at this diagram and the provided code options it seems all the calls are regular blocking calls from a single thread. In this context I can only interpret the unlabeled call as a return.  Also, wouldn't it be a bit strange to continue the activation block of d.u() after a blocking call is made? The block cannot ever handle events before t() returns.

Comment: I think you're right that this is the only solution that makes sense from the diagram.